# OpenGL ES 2.0/GLKit Vertex Transparency

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

What's the most efficient way to handle transparency when working with vertex data? I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0 as well as GLKit. The user has access to a `UISlider` control that determines what the alpha value should be for each vertex in the model (values 0 to 1). Currently, I have to cycle through each vertex in the model and modify the alpha level on the color coordinates in a for loop. This is incredibly inefficient and slows down processing. Is there another way to handle dynamic transparency for models using vertex data/VBOs? I don't believe GLKit has any built-in ways to handle this using materials or effects either. Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Comment: What about using a uniform in your fragment shader that would be used in place of that fragment's normal alpha value? You'd just have to set that once per frame, and not have to re-upload geometry.

Comment: I'm not even using shaders at this point (which sounds inefficient already), but it sounds like that may be the way to go? I'm using GLKit which is handling the default shader configuration using GLKBaseEffect. On the same point, I'm not entirely sure what using a "uniform in your fragment shader" even means...is there a good spot to read about this? Or other suggestions you have? ps - your Molecules app is amazing.

Comment: Could you try using glColor4f(1,1,1,X) before drawing the object you want to be transparent and setting it back to glColor4f(1,1,1,1) after the draw.

Comment: @kschins - I talk about shaders in the OpenGL ES 2.0 session of my course from a couple of years ago: http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewCourse?id=497193807&s=143441&ls=1 . My GPUImage framework is built around them, so you can see plenty of examples within there. Jeff LaMarche did a great introduction to the subject, as well: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/11/opengl-es-20-for-ios-chapter-4.html